# Verification on mock object not respect to test case

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito

Problem:

Let's say we have two different service

```
class ServiceA(serviceB: ServiceB) {

  def methodA(): String = {
    "methodA called"
    serviceB.methodB()
  }

  def methodA2(): String = {
    "methodA2 called"
    serviceB.methodB()
  }
}
```

I write two test method and try to verify methodB called or not. When I run two test cases separately, tests pass. When I run all test methods, verification gives wrong result for second test.
In test class context, mockito-verification records all calls on mock object. I think mockito-scala should reset verification counts on mock objects after each test

```
class ServiceATest extends FlatSpec with IdiomaticMockito {
  val serviceB: ServiceB = mock[ServiceB]
  val serviceA: ServiceA = new ServiceA(serviceB)
  "methodA" should "called" in {
    serviceA.methodA()
    serviceB.methodB wasCalled once // Passes
  }
  "methodA2" should "called" in {
    serviceA.methodA2()
    serviceB.methodB wasCalled once // Fail. was 2 times
  }
}
```

Btw I tried with mockito-core, it gives same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `serviceA` and `serviceB` objects are effectively test fixtures but you share them in a wrong way. With a code like yours the same objects are shared by all of the tests and it means that the tests interact with each other via shared dirty state. ScalaTest support many ways to [share fixtures](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures). One of the cleaner ways is the [loan pattern](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures#loanFixtureMethods) as in:

```
class ServiceATest extends FlatSpec with IdiomaticMockito {

  def withServicesAandBMock(testCode: (ServiceA, ServiceB) => Any) {
    val serviceB: ServiceB = mock[ServiceB]
    val serviceA: ServiceA = new ServiceA(serviceB)
    testCode(serviceA, serviceB)
  }

  "methodA" should "called" in withServicesAandBMock { (serviceA, serviceB) =>
    serviceA.methodA()
    serviceB.methodB wasCalled once // Passes
  }

  "methodA2" should "called" in withServicesAandBMock { (serviceA, serviceB) =>
    serviceA.methodA2()
    serviceB.methodB wasCalled once // now passes as well
  }
}
```

Alternatively you may use [`ResetMocksAfterEachTest`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#user-content-orgmockitointegrationsscalatestresetmocksaftereachtest)

```
class ServiceATest extends FlatSpec with IdiomaticMockito with ResetMocksAfterEachTest {

  val serviceB: ServiceB = mock[ServiceB]
  val serviceA: ServiceA = new ServiceA(serviceB)
  "methodA" should "called" in {
    serviceA.methodA()
    serviceB.methodB wasCalled once // Passes
  }
  "methodA2" should "called" in {
    serviceA.methodA2()
    serviceB.methodB wasCalled once // now passes as well
  }
}
```

but IMHO this is a kind of cheating

Comment: Also the standard way to solve it is to use an inner trait
https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/issues/74

Comment: @mstzn, this "inner trait" solution is the same loan pattern but structured a bit differently. I think which way you prefer depends on taste rather than on real practical merits. I'd also recommend you to read the already referenced [ScalaTest article](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures) to see some other options that might be useful in other scenarios.